# neo4j for fraud detection - efficient data structure

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to improve a fraud detection system for a commerce website. We deal with direct bank transactions, so fraud is a risk we need to manage. I recently learned of graphing databases and can see how it applies to these problems. So, over the past couple of days I set up neo4j and parsed our data into it: [example](http://pasteboard.co/rWwhyGc4O.png)

My intuition was to create a node for each order, and a node for each piece of data associated with it, and then connect them all together. Like this:

```
MATCH (w:Wallet),(i:Ip),(e:Email),(o:Order) 
WHERE w.wallet="ex" AND i.ip="ex" AND e.email="ex" AND o.refcode="ex" 
CREATE (w)-[:USED]->(o),(i)-[:USED]->(o),(e)-[:USED]->(o)
```

But this query runs very slowly as the database size increases (I assume because it needs to search the whole data set for the nodes I'm asking for). It also takes a long time to run a query like this:

```
START a=node(179) 
MATCH (a)-[:USED*]-(d) 
WHERE EXISTS(d.refcode) 
RETURN distinct d
```

This is intended to extract all orders that are connected to a starting point. I'm very new to Cypher (<24 hours), and I'm finding it particularly difficult to search for solutions.

Are there any specific issues with the data structure or queries that I can address to improve performance? It ideally needs to complete this kind of thing within a few seconds, as I'd expect from a SQL database. At this time we have about 17,000 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Always a good idea to completely read through the [developers manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/).

For speeding up lookups of nodes by a property, you definitely need to create [indexes or unique constraints](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/) (depending on if the property should be unique to a label/value).

Once you've created the indexes and constraints you need, they'll be used under the hood by your query to speed up your matches.

START is only used for legacy indexes, and for the latest Neo4j versions you should use MATCH instead. If you're matching based upon an internal id, you can use `MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = xxx`.

Keep in mind that you should not persist node ids outside of Neo4j for lookup in future queries, as internal node ids can be reused as nodes are deleted and created, so an id that once referred to a node that was deleted may later end up pointing to a completely different node.

Using labels in your queries should help your performance. In the query you gave to find orders, Neo4j must inspect every end node in your path to see if the property exists. Property access tends to be expensive, especially when you're using a variable-length match, so it's better to restrict the nodes you want by label.

```
MATCH (a)-[:USED*]-(d:Order)
WHERE id(a) = 179 
RETURN distinct d
```

On larger graphs, the variable-length match might start slowing down, so you may get more performance by installing [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and using the [Path Expander](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_with_config) procedure to gather all subgraph nodes and filter down to just Order nodes.

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE id(a) = 179
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(a, {bfs:true, uniqueness:"NODE_GLOBAL"}) YIELD path
RETURN LAST(NODES(path)) as d
WHERE d:Order
```